# Движение символа в C

Tags: c++, c

Как можно осуществить движение символа в C? И когда символ достигает определенной точки останавливался?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Если подразумевается необходимость в текстовом режиме сделать аналог бегущей строки, то посмотрите на функци из заголовочного файла `<conio.h>`

Comment: Мне надо осуществить движение символа в консоли по строке, и когда символ достигает определенной координаты, должен остановиться.

Comment: А можете примерный код написать???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Windows 2000 и выше можно использовать SetConsoleCursorPosition

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx